# Why does the co-efficent of kinetic friction of a block on an inclined plane not change when you increase the angle of the plane?

Tags: forces, friction

The coefficient of kinetic friction can be calculated using $\mu_k = F_k/F_n$. A change in angle does not affect the normal force, but doesn't a change in angle affect the friction? As in if the angle is steeper, wouldn't the object have a greater propensity to move down the slope, thus there will be less friction?

Comment: Where are you getting that it doesn't affect the normal force?

Comment: The normal force is determined by acceleration due to gravity, multiplied by the mass. So the angle does not affect the normal force.

Comment: Sorry, but that's simply wrong.

Comment: Okay, then I've been doing this wrong then!

Comment: Note that normal force is equal to mg only for a very specific situation. In general it is the force applied by the surfaces in contact on each other, along their common normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal force *does* decrease with angle. This does not mean that the coefficient of friction changes:

We can, depending on the angle $\theta$ of the slope, split the gravitational force $F_g = mg$ acting upon a thing with mass $m$ resting on the slope into the normal force $F_n = mg \cos(\theta)$ and the force pointing down the slope, $F_s = mg\sin(\theta)$.

Now, the coefficient of friction is a property of materials, and does not change with the angle - *but* it is the case that the friction force will decrease since it is $F_k = \mu_kF_n$. The "greater propensity" of things to slide down steeper inclined slopes is due to the friction force decreasing, and due to the force pointing down the slope *increasing* with *increasing* angle.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I was approaching the question in the wrong way. I will accsept this question as the right answer in 3 minutes. It says I have to wait.

Comment: @user2396852 In addition to this answer i totally agree with, note that this is only one (among many) contact *model*. For many experiments it will not give a good prediction of the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

*I am adding this answer to clear out an important point that seems to be the root of the doubt. Consider this an addition to the accepted answer.*

It sounds like this confusion comes from a misunderstanding of the normal force.

The normal force is *not* $n=mg$. Never ever think of that as some kind of formula. It *might* be equal to $mg$ by coincidence now and then, but *never* think of this as a general formula.

The only thing a normal force does is to hold back - it equals *whatever* it holds back against! Not necessarily $mg$.

- Does it happen to hold  back against gravity only, then yes, it is $n=mg$.
- Does it happen to hold back against gravity *and* you pushing down with a force $S$ as well, then it equals the total force $n=mg+S$ and is not equal to $mg$.
- Are you pushing with $S$ in a wall, then it holds back horizontally with $n=S$. Nothing about $mg$ here.

In  your situation, the normal force will hold back with $n=mg$ when the surface is horizontal (it must carry the full weight) and with $n=0$ when the surface is vertical (it carries nothing). In between these cases, we have a gradual change of $n$. When the surface has an angle, only a smaller portion is carried by the normal force, not the full weight and not zero. (When the normal force carries less than the full load in such an incline, then "the rest" of the load is carried by friction or not carried at all if the object is accelerating, as in your case).

Answer (score -1):

The change in incline angle does not affect the normal force$F_n$, but does affect the friction. As the angle becomes steeper, the binder has a greater propensity to move down the slope, thus there will be less friction.

Comment: Friction and normal force are related by the relation: $F_f= \mu F_n$. If one becomes larger, the other will become larger too.